# HighCharts data from HTML Table

Tags: highcharts

I am populating my highcharts column chart via html table. Is there a way to add custom attributes to a td so I can access them in the tooltip?

Comment: You can use the `style` attribute in your tooltip definition or you can use the `formatter` function to add some HTML stuffs into your tooltip.

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you have an example of this?

Comment: Highcharts has some great API documentation. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

Comment: Default parser, gets values frm td only, not pushing extra params. So you have two options. First use tooltip formatter and customise content (by adding condition / text or somehitng), or prepare your own HTML parser (i.e using jquery) and then use formatter to extract extra values.